# Apache not redirecting .co.uk to .com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I initially had my site at `https://example.co.uk`, but moved both hosting and domain and now use `https://www.example.com`. This involved moving my SSL certificate too.

I wanted to redirect visitors of the `.co.uk` site to the `.com`. So, I changed the `.htaccess` for my `.co.uk` to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) https://www.example.com/$1
```

When someone visits the old website at `http://` they are redirected to the new site, however, if they visit the old website with `https://` they are not redirected and hit a page stating the security certificate is non-existent.

I want all visits to `example.co.uk` to redirect, regardless of the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

or use this :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Does this take into account the `www.` of the new domain? Also what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Of curse the second code have `www` and more detail.